# Conditional import header file only if iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, customization

**Aim: my UINavigationBar has to be customized with a certain background and a specific label font.**

This is easily achievable in iOS5 with the appearance protocol. Ok.

What if my user runs < iOS5? He will see default UINavigationBar, but not if I extend UINavigationBar with a category that overrides drawRect.

**Question 1:** How can I specify in my Prefix.pch a conditional #import of UINavigationBar category extension according to iOS version?

**Question 2:** Assuming I manage to solve question 1, will this work? I mean, if the device is not iOS5 I am NOT setting [UINavigationBar] appearance] but only importing the category, do I need to do something more?

**EDIT:** This is the implementation of Vladimir suggestion, I don't have a iOS4 device nor simulator to test it right now but I think it might work.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (iOS4Appearance)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    if (self.isiOS5) {
        [super drawRect];
    } else {
        UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation-bar"];
        [background drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}

- (BOOL)isiOS5
{
    return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0;
}

@end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with #import, since that's compile-time, and you can only upload one binary to the app store (which should be iOS-version-independent). Instead, you can test this at runtime. For example, you can override drawRect, but depending on the [iOS version](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) you'll either call super or run your own code.

EDIT:

My suggestion won't work with plain categories because they replace the original implementation. There are at least two alternatives:

1. Subclassing UINavigationBar and overriding drawRect.
2. [Method swizzling](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) the drawRect on existing UINavigationBar instances.

Comment: That's very clever @Vladimir, I didn't think about that. So you are saying in my Prefix.pch I import ALWAYS my UINavigationBar category but in UINavigationBar.m drawRect I test the iOS version, and if iOS5 if call [super drawRect] otherwise I run my code. Correct?

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi, exactly :-)

Comment: little problem though, this is a category not a subclass, therefore it seems I can't call either [super drawRect] nor [UINavigationBar drawRect]....

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer to reflect implementations that work better than categories in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but I am  not instancing UINavigationBar programmatically, I believe I can't use alternative 1, don't know alternative 2 enough to say...

Comment: And another consideration, maybe this is not needed at all, because it seems iOS5 is not even entering the category, therefore if it gets there only for < iOS5 drawRect can stay without if clause? What do you think?

Comment: Maybe iOS 5 uses a different class for implementation (subclasses and doesn't call super? uses a class cluster?). I wouldn't depend on this behavior. Alternative #2 should be good enough. Methods in Objective C are just function pointers in a classes' method list. Swizzling methods means swapping the original pointer with your own. It's a very powerful technique and I recommend reading up on it (there's more info on the web and SO, though I think Mike Ash explains it quite well).